# I get an undefined error in firebug , even if I can see the value exists!...why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, firebug

i'm loading in jquery a google map json and i receive correctly the json object called 'data'

sometimes —  i can't identify exactly when or why and that's why i came here — 
even if i receive the regular values, BUT firebug console reads it is **undefined**!

for example, I have this line below in my js:

```
console.log(data.Placemark[i].AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.SubAdministrativeArea.Locality.PostalCode.PostalCodeNumber);
```

in my Firebug Console i can see first the right value of the zipcode (10018), THEN i see this error:

**data.Placemark[i].AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.SubAdministrativeArea.Locality.PostalCode is undefined**

i mean, if I get the value.. how could it be that is undefined??

here the complete code

```
   $.ajax(
    {
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=" + myaddress + "&key=" + myapiKey + "&sensor=false&output=json&callback=?",
        success: function (data, textStatus)
        {
      for (i = 0; i < data.Placemark.length; i++)
      {

   console.log(data.Placemark[i].AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.SubAdministrativeArea.Locality.PostalCode.PostalCodeNumber);   
      }

        },
        error: function (data)
        {  
  /*nothing*/
        }
    });
```

I can add another detail: the error happens only when data.length is > 1 (basically when i get more than one address corresponding to my input)

Comment: Is `data` a global variable?  If not, I wouldn't expect you to see it in the Firebug console.  Try putting the `console.log` line in your JavaScript code where `data` is lexically available.

Comment: i updated my question with complete code, but is strange because most fo the time i get a regular response...other times not..i even thought thet could be the value the problem...

Comment: @frankB: Which line triggers that error?

Comment: the console.log triggers the error, that one but even other use of the value data..etc...is stange becaus efirstly i se the value of the zip code and then the error!

Comment: I can add another detail: the error happens only when data.length is > 1 (basically when i get more than one address corresponding to my input)

Comment: What happens when you do this? `try {console.log(data.Placemark[i].AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.SubAdministrativeArea.Locality.PostalCode.PostalCodeNumber);} catch (err) {console.log(data.Placemark[i].AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.SubAdministrativeArea.Locality);}`

Answer (score 1):

I think you said it all. When the loop runs more than once (which is when the length is > 1), you're iterating through the second item, which doesn't have the property it trips up on. The first iteration does.